# Cannot lower/figure out per connection mariadb memory usage

Tags: mariadb, memory, max-connections, mysqltuner

I'm running a small mariadb DB to serve some websites and monitoring tools (nexctloud, wordpress and icinga2). The machine that works as a DB server also run an elasticsearch + graylog instance so I wanted to lower the maximu memory footprint mariadb could reach.
Running mysqltuner gives me the following memory results:

```
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.4G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 4.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 2.7G global + 19.7M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 95M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 2.9G (38.83% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 4.7G (63.35% of installed RAM)
```

I cannot figure out how the 19.7 M per connection is calculated as the sum of

read_buffer_size + 
read_rnd_buffer_size + 
sort_buffer_size + 
join_buffer_size + 
binlog_cache_size + 
thread_stack

is by far lower than that.

Here's my my.cnf file

```
[client]
default_character_set = utf8mb4
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mysqld_safe]
log_error = /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
nice = 0
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

[mariadb]
ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem
ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-cert.pem
ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl/server-key.pem
tls_version = TLSv1.2,TLSv1.3

[mysqld]
basedir = /usr
#bind_address = 0.0.0.0
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
max_allowed_packet = 16M
pid_file = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
port = 3306
skip_external_locking
skip_name_resolve
socket = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
tmpdir = /dev/shm
user = mysql
##tmpdir = /tmp

character-set-server = utf8mb4
collation-server = utf8mb4_general_ci
concurrent_insert = 2
connect_timeout = 5
interactive_timeout = 600
wait_timeout = 600
lc_messages_dir = /usr/share/mysql
lc_messages = en_US
transaction_isolation = READ-COMMITTED

###temp tables
tmp_table_size = 64M
max_heap_table_size = 64M

###innodb settings
default_storage_engine = InnoDB
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 2500M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances = 2
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
innodb_log_buffer_size = 16M
innodb_log_file_size = 384M
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 90
innodb_file_per_table = 1
innodb_open_files = 400
innodb_io_capacity = 4000
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_stats_on_metadata = 0

###connections
max_connections = 100

###buffer settings
read_buffer_size = 1M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 1M
sort_buffer_size = 1M
join_buffer_size = 512K
key_buffer_size = 128K

###log
expire_logs_days = 7
general_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql.log
general_log = 0
skip-log-bin
log_error=/var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log
log_slow_verbosity = query_plan
log_warnings = 2
slow_query_log_file = /var/log/mysql/mysql_slow.log
slow_query_log = 1

###query cache
query_cache_type = 0
query_cache_size = 0
table_definition_cache = 8000 # UPD
table_open_cache = 40000 # UPD
open_files_limit = 60000
thread_stack = 192K
thread_cache_size = 100
back_log = 512

myisam_recover_options = BACKUP

[mysqldump]
host = localhost
port = 3306
max_allowed_packet = 16M
quick
quote_names

[isamchk]
!include /etc/mysql/mariadb.cnf
!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
key_buffer = 10M
```

thank you very much!

This is my mysqltuner output, unfortunately the mysql instance is running only since 14 hours due to a kernel update but usually these are the usual results (in terms of warnings and recommendations) I get after weeks of uptime

```
-------- Performance Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Up for: 14h 7m 30s (482K q [9.485 qps], 9K conn, TX: 1G, RX: 64M)
[--] Reads / Writes: 90% / 10%
[--] Binary logging is disabled
[--] Physical Memory     : 7.4G
[--] Max MySQL memory    : 4.7G
[--] Other process memory: 0B
[--] Total buffers: 2.7G global + 19.7M per thread (100 max threads)
[--] P_S Max memory usage: 95M
[--] Galera GCache Max memory usage: 0B
[OK] Maximum reached memory usage: 3.0G (40.12% of installed RAM)
[OK] Maximum possible memory usage: 4.7G (63.35% of installed RAM)
[OK] Overall possible memory usage with other process is compatible with memory available
[OK] Slow queries: 0% (0/482K)
[OK] Highest usage of available connections: 10% (10/100)
[OK] Aborted connections: 0.00%  (0/9725)
[OK] Query cache is disabled by default due to mutex contention on multiprocessor machines.
[OK] Sorts requiring temporary tables: 0% (0 temp sorts / 8K sorts)
[!!] Joins performed without indexes: 4747
[OK] Temporary tables created on disk: 9% (11K on disk / 122K total)
[OK] Thread cache hit rate: 99% (10 created / 9K connections)
[OK] Table cache hit rate: 97% (235 open / 241 opened)
[OK] table_definition_cache(8000) is upper than number of tables(353)
[OK] Open file limit used: 0% (57/80K)
[OK] Table locks acquired immediately: 100% (900 immediate / 900 locks)

-------- Performance schema ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Memory used by P_S: 95.5M
[--] Sys schema is installed.

-------- ThreadPool Metrics ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] ThreadPool stat is enabled.
[--] Thread Pool Size: 4 thread(s).
[--] Using default value is good enough for your version (10.4.12-MariaDB-1:10.4.12+maria~buster-log)

-------- MyISAM Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[!!] Key buffer used: 24.2% (31K used / 131K cache)
[!!] Cannot calculate MyISAM index size - re-run script as root user

-------- InnoDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] InnoDB is enabled.
[--] InnoDB Thread Concurrency: 0
[OK] InnoDB File per table is activated
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool / data size: 2.5G/69.8M
[OK] Ratio InnoDB log file size / InnoDB Buffer pool size: 384.0M * 2/2.5G should be equal to 25%
[OK] InnoDB buffer pool instances: 2
[--] Number of InnoDB Buffer Pool Chunk : 20 for 2 Buffer Pool Instance(s)
[OK] Innodb_buffer_pool_size aligned with Innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size & Innodb_buffer_pool_instances
[OK] InnoDB Read buffer efficiency: 99.93% (9223051 hits/ 9229566 total)
[!!] InnoDB Write Log efficiency: 83.88% (41174 hits/ 49089 total)
[OK] InnoDB log waits: 0.00% (0 waits / 7915 writes)

-------- AriaDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] AriaDB is enabled.
[OK] Aria pagecache size / total Aria indexes: 128.0M/312.0K
[OK] Aria pagecache hit rate: 99.7% (678K cached / 1K reads)

-------- TokuDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] TokuDB is disabled.

-------- XtraDB Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] XtraDB is disabled.

-------- Galera Metrics ----------------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera is disabled.

-------- Replication Metrics -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[--] Galera Synchronous replication: NO
[--] No replication slave(s) for this server.
[--] Binlog format: MIXED
[--] XA support enabled: ON
[--] Semi synchronous replication Master: OFF
[--] Semi synchronous replication Slave: OFF
[--] This is a standalone server

-------- Recommendations ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
General recommendations:
    Control warning line(s) into /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log file
    Control error line(s) into /var/log/mysql/mysql_error.log file
    Set up a Secure Password for netdata@localhost user: SET PASSWORD FOR 'netdata'@'SpecificDNSorIp' = PASSWORD('secure_password');
    MySQL was started within the last 24 hours - recommendations may be inaccurate
    We will suggest raising the 'join_buffer_size' until JOINs not using indexes are found.
             See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/join-buffer-size.html
             (specially the conclusions at the bottom of the page).
Variables to adjust:
    join_buffer_size (> 512.0K, or always use indexes with JOINs)
```

Comment: Add max_allowed_packet, net_buffer_length, net_buffer_length to your list  You have one buffer for input, another for output.  There may be others I can not think of at the moment.  Posting the complete MySQLTuner report would be helpful to view the overall health of your system.  Some (a few) MySQLTuner recommendations should NOT be implemented.  Be careful, keep dated copies of your configuration to allow quickly returning to last working config.  One change a day is a good limit to allow monitoring of the specific change before changing the next one.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I've just posted the whole mysqltuner output, thanks
If I add the actual max_allowed_packet (which is actually set to 16M) to the count the mysqltuner result makes sense

Comment: Additional information request. 
Any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions for lowering the RAM footprint. Pls view profile.

Comment: Running MySQLTuner as root will provide additional helpful information.

Comment: @WilsonHauck yes, the DB is on a SSD drive, I always rung mysqltuner as root but it still tells me "Cannot calculate MyISAM index size - re-run script as root user", strange. It is a very small db although growing, the mysql memory is usually mid/low but the maximum possible memory usage worries me. Until now the top mysql mem usage I've seen is about 19/20% of the total ram.

GLOBAL STATUS -> https://pastebin.com/FaBU2k0N
GLOBAL VARIABLES -> https://pastebin.com/3Fj2ZXU2
FULL PROCESSLIST -> https://pastebin.com/pUnDVMCj
other system stats -> https://pastebin.com/f266wGJn

Comment: @ebiagi - Which "root" -- the OS's root or MariaDB's root?

Comment: @RickJames the OS root, I do a sudo -s and then launch mysqltuner.

Comment: @ebiagi - The connection from mysqltuner to MySQL needs to be mysql's root.

Comment: @RickJames ok, but if I input my mariadb root ones it gives me the "Cannot calculate MyISAM index size - re-run script as root user" stil

Comment: The script needs to be run as OS "root", but the connection to the database needs to be as MySQL's "root".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
table_open_cache=500  # from 40,000 less than 400 opened_tables in 36 hours
table_definition_cache=500  # from 8,000 less than 200 opened_table_definitions in 36 h
sort_buffer_size=512K  # from 1M to conserve RAM, expect sort_merge_passes of 4 to increase
max_connections=32  # from 100 to support your max_used_connection of 15 in 36 h
```

You will find your RAM footprint is smaller in 'top' report with no performance penalty.  View my profile, Network profile for contact info and free downloadable Utility Scripts to assist with performance tuning.  Consider adding 8GB RAM when usage increases.

Indexes are needed to reduce select_scan Rate Per Second of 3.

```
log_slow_verbosity=query_plan,explain  # from query_plan to enhance Slow Log.
```

Answer (score 0):

**The flawed formula**

The per-connection memory computation is wrong.  Find another formula tomorrow, I can tell you *today* that it will be wrong.  There is no formula that is correct.  Furthermore, the formula is both too high and too low.

Most formulas are too high in that they are "worst case" -- `max_connections` connections are all busy with complex queries.  Even if you are using "max_connections", probably most of them are doing different things.

Most formulas are also too low.  A "complex" query may be so complex that it needs more than one of various buffers.  But the formula assumes only one.

I gave up on "max memory" long ago.

**Other tips**

Your settings mostly look OK.  However, these are excessive:

```
table_definition_cache = 8000 # UPD
table_open_cache = 40000 # UPD
```

The units are "tables", not "bytes".  If you have thousands of tables, you have other problems.

`Open_tables` is only 246, so `table_open_cache` can probably be set to a few hundred.  (Ditto for the other setting.)

`Max_used_connections` (only 15) is a lot less than `max_connections` (now 100), so the latter can be lowered.

If you are having performance problems with WordPress, here is a tip:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#speeding_up_wp_postmeta